# Objective C block works by passing in pointer of pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, pass-by-reference

Run this code and get `x is 11` in console. Changing states of variables outside a method scope looks like a block behavior to me. Is that how block works?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    [self doSomethingWithNumber:&x];
    NSLog(@"x is %@ \n",x);

}

- (BOOL)doSomethingWithNumber:(NSNumber**)aNumber
{
    *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, whoever downvotes this question please leaves a comment. I think it's a real question that deserves an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the unorthodox syntax of your example - which I presume is contrived just to illustrate a point - it is correct that blocks capture state from the lexical scope in which they are defined.  For more about the internals, take a look at [this post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1749597&seqNum=12) from Mark Dalrymple on blocks internals.

Normally variables from the surrounding scope have pass-by-value semantics within the block and pass-by-reference semantics with the `__block` modifier.  Thus, this would <del>throw an exception</del> not compile *(EDIT 2012-09-27 20-52-51)*:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef int (^IntBlock)();

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        int n = 5;
        IntBlock alwaysEleven = ^{ 
            n++; 
            printf("n inside the block: %d\n",n);
            return 11;
        };
        int d = alwaysEleven(n);
        printf("result = %d, n = %d", d,n);

        [p release];
    }
```

but if we declare `__block int n = 5;` it would not.

@leo suggested Getting Started with Blocks.  If you are interested in how the block captures state and where the captured state lives (on the stack until `Block_copy()`) then the Blocks Programming Topics in the documentation is a worthwhile read.

Comment: "Normally variables from the surrounding scope have pass-by-value semantics within the block and pass-by-reference semantics with the __block modifier. " That clears my head. Many thanks!

Comment: "Thus, this would throw an exception" I think it is a compile error

Comment: But capture-by-value semantics does not necessarily imply that you cannot assign to it -- that is a language choice. For example, with C++11 lambdas, variables captured by value can still be assigned to, if the lambda is declared `mutable`.

Comment: @NSBum, I come back to this question four months later, and now I truly understand your answer. Learning takes patience, and help from people like you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's how pointers work. If you want to do something with blocks, then follow Apple's [Getting Started with Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html) or one of the many fine tutorials [on the web](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/programming-with-blocks-an-overview/).

Comment: I know the block syntax. My question regards the internal mechanism of block. More specifically, is block keep variables' state in surrounding context by covertly passing in variable pointer?